# Why do I see a number in the title while googling this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, google

I googled ["is Dijkstra's algorithm for undirected graphs"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=is%20dijkstra%27s%20algorithm%20for%20undirected%20graphs) and the first result I got was on Stack Overflow, but the title has the number "19" in it:

[image]

But the actual title is "[Is Dijkstra's algorithm for directed or undirected graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190592/is-dijkstras-algorithm-for-directed-or-undirected-graphs)" without the number "19". I looked around on that page, but I couldn't find the number "19" in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38190592/revisions).

So where does this number come from? I haven't seen this before while googling stuff.

Comment: Could it be the vote score of the question at the point when Google cached the page?

Comment: As for the why, because it can. Because it can be use to order result. Because that's how Google’s featured snippets works for StackOverflow. Click the "about featured snipet" to learn more.

Comment: Khelwood seems to be right, I found another instance of this happening: [is order maintained in a tuple](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=is+order+maintained+in+a+tuple). `26` is added before the title, the vote count is `28`.